# Drush 10 sql-sync and multi site --uri not working

Tags: drush

I am doing some D8 to D9 migrations and having a problem with a multisite. I upgraded my local version to drush 10 as well as on my dev server and included the `drush/sites/us2.site.yml` file.

I can sql-sync the default db no problem, but when I try and specify a `--uri` it still targets my default database.

`drush sql-sync @us2.dev @self` says it will replace `us2_local` with `us2dev` which is correct.

`drush sql-sync @us2.dev @self --uri="reports"` says it will replace `us2_reports_local` with `us2dev`. That is incorrect. The source DB should be a different database in this case. It did get the target database correct as my local db is `us2_reports_local`.

if I do `drush @us2.dev status` database points to `us2dev`

if I do `drush @us2.dev status --uri="reports"` it shows the correct us2 reports db so status seems to work, but not sql-sync

Any ideas? I feel like I am missing something obvious. I am still on the latest version of drupal 8 until I get the modules up to date.

Comment: `--uri` passes a URL (eg. `http://example.com/`) that is used as the URL accessing Drupal. 'reports' doesn't look valid. What is it you're t trying to do with `--uri`?

Comment: `reports` is a site defined in the sites.php file used in multisite. For example, in sites.php `$sites['reports.us2.local'] = 'reports';`. If I pass that URL instead of the site name, it still does not work @Jaypan

Comment: I don't believe that's what `--uri` does. It sounds like you need to set up a drush alias, and set the URI there. Then you can call drush with the alias.

Comment: That was indeed the problem @Jaypan. I still have to specify --uri in order for sql-sync to select the correct local DB which I find odd. I may not have the new reports.site.yml entirely correct

Comment: for example: `drush sql-sync @reports.dev @self` results in replace `us2_local` with `us2dev-reports`

`drush sql-sync @reports.dev @self --uri=reports` results in the correct local db: replace `us2_reports_local` with `us2dev-reports`